# PyAutoGUI para teclado virtual

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

Estou trabalhando em um projeto usando o Python 3.7 e a biblioteca PyAutoGUI.

Tenho um site que precisa fazer o login usando o mouse para digitar em um teclado virtual.

O problema é que o teclado muda de posição a cada click.

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca entrei na parte avançada desse modulo, mas sei como fazer isso:

o PAG (mais fácil chamar assim) também sabe buscar imagens na tela, baseadas nas que ele tem disponível:

```
PAG.locateOnScreen('print.png')
```

Sendo "print.png" a print da tecla
*a print da tecla precisa estar no mesmo diretório do seu .py, acredito que exista outro meio sem ter as print no mesmo path, mas não cheguei no avançado desse modulo.

Pode definir o valor de cada tecla com o nome da foto, dai usando apenas a variável no comando:

```
a = 'a.png'
b = 'b.png'
PAG.locateOnScreen(a)
PAG.locateOnScreen(b)
...
```

Já sabe agora como achar a tecla, agora tem que clicar nela.
o comando `PyAutoGui.click()` deve clicar, mas não na sua imagem, ainda...

```
 a = 'a.png'
 b = 'b.png'
 a_X,a_Y=PAG.locateCenterOnScreen(a)
 b_X,b_Y=PAG.locateCenterOnScreen(b)

 PAG.click(a_X,a_Y)
 PAG.click(b_X,b_Y)
```

Assim, ele vai procurar o centro da imagem que você forneceu, o que vai dar as coordenadas dela na sua tela, depois, ele vai clicar nas coordenadas que foram fornecidas pelo `LocateCenterOnScreen()`

Mas, como seu teclado muda a cada click, em vez de procurar as coordenadas de todas as teclas e depois clicar, mude seu código para procurar e clicar, procurar e clicar. se possível, de um `from time import sleep` e coloque `sleep(0.2)` depois de cada clique para dar um delay, pode ser que o teclado demore mais que seu código.
Lembre também de substitui o `PAG` do exemplo por `PyAutoGui` ou qualquer outro nome que você deu a ele. espero que seja isso que esteja procurando, boa sorte!

PyAutoGui Docs: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Edit1: é provável que o site tenha uma segurança contra isso, não é difícil fazer um programa que localiza a imagem. se tiver, me informe que talvez eu consigo ajudar nisso também.

Edit2: exemplo de como deve ficar seu
[diretório](https://prnt.sc/o3y0z0)

Comment: Primeiro eu tiro print da tela certo ? Depois eu coloco essa imagem dentro do meu 'projeto.py' ?

Comment: print da tecla, tipo A, B, C, em .png. salva a print na mesma pasta que esta seu .py

Comment: para números é a mesma coisa ?

Comment: sim, para numeros e letras, qualquer coisa, apenas tire uma print com um nome, dentro do seu código defina uma variável com seu valor sendo o nome da sua print, Exemplo: d_key = "D_key.png"

Comment: ok. Obrigado! :)